# How to de-italicize text after using \therefore?

Tags: math-mode, errors

I am trying to write a normal statement after using the `\therefore` symbol.

```
\therefore The mixed strategies (\frac{23}{27},\frac{4}{27}), (\frac{23}{27},\frac{4}{27}) are a Nash Equilibrium.
```

It gives me output like :

*[Therefore Symbol]Themixedstrategies(23/27,4/27),(23/27,4/27)areaNashEquilibrium.*

How do I make it normal text? Also, is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Look at the log file, you get at least one error. `\therefore` needs to be used in mathmode -> `$\therefore$` Same is true for the fractions. I suggest to have a look at [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html)

Comment: after an error message ask about the _error_ do not even look at the pdf output (which is usually meaningless after an error, tex's error recovery only tries to recover enough to check more command syntax, it does not attempt to make sensible output)

Answer (score 2):

With package `amssymb` you can simply write (see the used `$` in difference to your code):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
$\therefore$ The mixed strategies ($\frac{23}{27}$,$\frac{4}{27}$), 
($\frac{23}{27}$,$\frac{4}{27}$) are a Nash Equilibrium.
\end{document}
```

which gives you the result:

[image]

Please next question add an MWE, an short minimal compilable code ...